# How to ignoreeof on next bash?

Tags: bash

If I use export variable method, the next bash shell can ignore eof(press ^D won't exit).
But, I want the child bash could exit by press ^D.
Is there any command line option of bash could do this job?

```
export ignoreeof=1
exec bash  # assume this bash's pid = 1234
bash$  ^D  
bash$  Use "exit" to leave the shell.
bash$  bash  # assume this bash's pid = 2234
bash$  ^D  <--  I wish this could exit bash(pid=2234)
```

Comment: The variable needs to be in all-caps: `IGNOREEOF=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

William, Thanks your hint.

```
exec bash -o ignoreeof # assume this bash's pid = 1234
bash$  ^D  
bash$  Use "exit" to leave the shell.
bash$  bash  # assume this bash's pid = 2234
bash$  ^D  <--  exit bash(pid=2234)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ignoreeof=0 exec bash
```

should do the trick

Comment: Just tried.  It can not work. The child bash inside bash will inherit the environment variable ignoreeof.

Comment: The process that is exec'd (it is not a child, but rather the shell becomes the new shell) will have ignoreeof set to 0.

Comment: Could you re-read my question, I've give an example.  Maybe you mis-understood my question.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I gave?  It will make the first ^D actually exit the shell.  If you do not want that, and only want the second ^D to exit the second shell, the you should invoke `ignoreeof=0 bash` instead of just `bash`

Comment: If you prefer, you can do `bash +o ignoreeof`, but the effect is the same as `ignoreeof=0 bash`